# Variables from stdin

Tags: bash, unix

I want to get an input from the user using read

```
read line
```

and the proper input would be a string and then a number:

```
a 5
b 6
+ 87
```

How do you separate the "a" and 5 into two variables, with the 5 into a integer variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest reading the documenentation of `read` to get you started:

```
help read
```

Here are the first two paragraphs:

> Read a line from the standard input and split it into fields.
>
> Reads a single line from the standard input, or from file descriptor FD
>       if the -u option is supplied.  The line is split into fields as with word
>       splitting, and the first word is assigned to the first NAME, the second
>       word to the second NAME, and so on, with any leftover words assigned to
>       the last NAME.  Only the characters found in $IFS are recognized as word
>       delimiters.

Note that bash doesn't have a notion of "integer variables" comparable to other programming languages.  [Bash variables are untyped.](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/untyped.html)  Declaring a variable as integer using `declare -i` only influences assignments to this variable -- everything that is not a valid integer is silently set to `0`.

Comment: FYI - [Bash variables can be assigned types using `typeset`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/declareref.html)

Comment: Thanks I got the read part working, but if I don't set the second variable as an integer then I can't use it in math right? Because that's what i need to do

Comment: @JA3N: You can.  Follow the link in my post to see examples.

Comment: @D.Shawley: I'm aware of this.  I should probably change the wording of this answer.

Answer (score 2):

`read` supports the command line option `-a`, to store the input in an array like that:

```
$ read -a line
a 4
$ echo ${line[0]}
a
$ echo ${line[1]}
4
```

That would be nicer than using two variables, in my opinion.

Comment: I disagree.  Having two rather unrelated values of different type in an array is not nice.  Why do you think it's nicer?

Comment: I agree with Sven's disagreement. Two values of different purpose do not belong in an array together -- two variables seems far better.

Comment: If they were unrelated they would not be put in a single line, I suppose.  But it is totally your choice whether you want to store them in two variables or in an array.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're operating in the shell since this post is tagged "bash" but you might want to make that explicit.

Anyway, the "read" command to the shell takes multiple variable names, not just one. You can give it two and it will hand each word on the line to you in the respective variables. (They're split on the field separator given by the IFS variable.)

The shell doesn't really have any distinction between "integer" variables and any other kind in the general case.

I suggest reading the man page for the shell fully if you really want to understand how to write shell scripts properly.

Answer (score 0):

The `read` command will split your input along whatever is in `$IFS`. This, by default is *whitespace*, so simply doing this:

```
read my_string my_number
```

will split your input into two sections separated by the space. Sometimes, you'll see this:

```
read my_string my_number garbage
```

Because read will read in the entire rest of the line into the last variable no matter how many parameters you had. For example, if I had:

```
read my_string my_number
```

And the user put in:

```
this 1 foo foo foo!
```

`$my_string` will be `this`, but `$my_number` will be `1 foo foo foo!`

By putting another variable (called `garbage` in this case), I eliminate this issue. If I put:

```
read my_string my_number garbage
```

And the user put in:

```
this 1 foo foo foo!
```

`$my_string` will be `this`, `$my_number` will be `1`, and `$garbage` would be `foo foo foo!`.

A simple test program:

```
while read my_string my_number garbage
do
  echo "The string is '$my_string'. The number is '$my_number'."
  echo "Note there's no error checking of input."
  echo "That's your job, Bunky."
done
```